# How to route IotHub /messages/servicebound/feedback to service Bus in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-servicebus-queues

Is there a way to route the /messages/servicebound/feedback to the service bus queue in Azure?

Comment: No, there is no built-in a routing mechanism for this service-facing endpoint in the Azure IoT Hub. To obtain a feedback for cloud-to-device messages can be used a REST GET request https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/cloud-to-device-messages/receive-feedback-notification, in other words, you have to use a mechanism of the polling and forwarding notification messages to the service bus entity.